# Camera calibration using 3D points

Tags: opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I know the classical tools for camera calibration use a planar board that we know its dimension.

My problem is slightly different. Instead of having a planar board, I do have some 3D points that I know their coordinates (6 dof) with respect to the camera. Those 3D points can be detected in the image, so we know their pixel coordinates.

Is there any tools that can calibration the camera using 3D points?

Comment: Have you tried calling 

`ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)` 

with objpoints being your 3D points? In theory this should work even if the points are not on one coordinate plane.

Comment: @Olli I didn't try it, I could do that but in the documentation, it is stated that objpoints is a vector of vectors of calibration pattern points IN the calibration pattern coordinate space which is not my case, I've points in the camera coordinate space.

Comment: I think 3D points should work, but you will have to provide an initial guess for the camera matrix, because the automatic guess assumes planar object points.

Comment: @Micka by using the regular calibration function calibrateCamera?
Okay I'll give it try